Unable to get data for the selected rows in lightning data table using getSelectedRows
<lightning-datatable key-field="Product2Id"
            data={productRecords}
            columns={productconfigcolumns}
            onsave={handleSave}
            draft-values={saveDraftValues}
            show-row-number-column
            onrowselection= {selectedRowHandler}
            class="productconfigtable">
            </lightning-datatable>
<lightning-button onclick={handleclick} value="Demo" label="Demo"></lightning-button>

handleclick(){
        var el = this.template.querySelector('.productconfigtable');
        console.log(el);
        var selected = el.getSelectedRows();
        console.log(selected);
    }

Although the getSelectedRows is returning the selected rows, the returned rows are empty


Do you have checked this? - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation#:~:text=Managing%20Selected%20Rows

Almost every non primitive value is wrapped in a proxy object by default, so it may happens that you don't see its true content in console.log, anyway it doesn't mean that the row is empty. You could either enable debug mode or print a primitive property (i.e. console.log(selected[0].Product2Id);) or stringify the whole object (i.e. console.log(JSON.stringify(selected);)

Try
console.log(JSON.stringify(selected));


This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
